# ORM::cached() won't work

Tags: php, kohana

I got setup everything right,
caching inside Kohana::init is true,
reload_on_wakup inside model is false
and caching ORM still won't work, I mean, it creates instance of filled file but when tried to load this cached file, it executes new query instead, like cache time expired,
Kohana 3.3.1, Linux x64, php 5.4

## edit solved

Comment: try to add the number of seconds to cache in the cached() method. ->cached(6000)

Comment: I did it, but won't work either

Comment: Can you please show me your cache config, and your "orm build query", i mean, ORM::factory('User')->cached()->find_all();

Answer (score 0):

Please do this debug,

```
$orm = ORM::factory('Your_Model')->cached(5)->find_all(); // cached 5 seconds
echo Debug::vars($orm);
```

Everytime that is cached it will display object Database_Result_Cached(), whenever it refreshes it will show the Database_MySQL_Result, so you know if it's working.

This is working in the default config's from Kohana 3.3, check the permissions on the cache folder as well, if you are using the file driver.

But please update your question with the cache config file so i can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for trying help. but I forgot about that I overrided _load_result method and there I used time() as parameter of query, instead time() I use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() now, anyway thanks